# How to add dynamically css in AngularJS?

Tags: css, angularjs

Hi I am trying to add css dynamically but it's not working bellow is my code

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'myApp.controllers','myApp.services']).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/new', { templateUrl: 'partials/add.html', controller: 'add' ,resolve: {
style : function(){
  /* check if already exists first - note ID used on link element*/
  /* could also track within scope object*/
alert("DSAF");
    angular.element('head').append('  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>');

}
}})  }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without more info on your code it will be difficult to help but anyway here are a two (easy) things that come to my mind :

- Be sure that the path css/app.css redirects to a file i.e no 404,
- `angular.element('head')` will work only if jquery is loaded before angular otherwise you will have an error regarding jqLite.

Finally I have assemble a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qEAaxhkkDBOxSoJUk5eg?p=preview) where everything is working the way it should base on your extract of code. Let me know if it helps.